# compare 2 times and if past midnight then mark it as next day

Tags: excel, vba

I have a log file with 420,000 lines of logon entries, I have a time stamp in Column D and a logon name in Column E. Now I don't know when the log file was started but I can see where today's logons are so wanted to work backwards through the sheet.

So now to the question, I have todays logons and the last entry (working backwards) is:

```
06:09:42 | Joe Bloggs
```

Then the one above it is:

```
21:27:36 | Adam Jones
```

Is there a way of running through Column A and when you get to this situation start inputting the previous days date.

EDIT:

This is the code I have at the moment don't know if it is the best way to do it:

```
Sub DateStamp()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    strDate = Date

    Do Until lRow = 2

        If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value > WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value + TimeSerial(12, 0, 0) Then
            strDate = strDate - 1
            WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate
        Else
            WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate
        End If

        lRow = lRow - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

This code doesn't quite work at the moment as any time that is close to midnight will then mark it as the next day

Example entries[image: example entries]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How about *"Is the previous row's time larger than the current row's time?"*

Comment: @Chronocidal Have now added the code, sorry forgot to

Comment: What's your meaning of (any time that is close to midnight will then mark it as the next day)?

Comment: Can't see any example entry

Comment: @Igor image should be visible now, working from bottom up when it’s gets to the previous days time (going from the 06:09:42 to the 21:27:36 entry) i would like the date added to column B to be the previous days date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. Last row refers to today date
2. You have enough log row for each day
3. Your row 1 is an header, row 2 contains data
4. Following data could be example entries for your problem

   ```
   NotInteresting  |DateGoesHere   |NotInteresting |Time       |Logon_Name
   1               |               |This           |13:06:24   |Adam Jones
   2               |               |column         |16:40:56   |Bill Bao
   3               |               |is             |03:02:30   |Joe Bloggs
   4               |               |not            |08:41:02   |Jhon Doe
   5               |               |interesting    |19:30:36   |Iam Igor
   6               |               |but            |04:06:52   |Pinco Pallino
   7               |               |I              |13:49:59   |Romolo Remo
   8               |               |know           |17:08:04   |Harry Potter
   9               |               |that           |18:26:52   |Jane Doe
   10              |               |last           |21:27:36   |Adam Jones
   11              |               |row            |06:09:42   |Joe Bloggs
   12              |               |date           |07:00:02   |Iam Igor
   13              |               |is today       |12:40:08   |Pinco Pallino
   ```

   and the expected result is:

   ```
   NotInteresting  |DateGoesHere       |NotInteresting |Time       |Logon_Name
   1               |   29/04/2020      |This           |13:06:24   |Adam Jones
   2               |   29/04/2020      |column         |16:40:56   |Bill Bao
   3               |   30/04/2020      |is             |03:02:30   |Joe Bloggs
   4               |   30/04/2020      |not            |08:41:02   |Jhon Doe
   5               |   30/04/2020      |interesting    |19:30:36   |Iam Igor
   6               |   01/05/2020      |but            |04:06:52   |Pinco Pallino
   7               |   01/05/2020      |I              |13:49:59   |Romolo Remo
   8               |   01/05/2020      |know           |17:08:04   |Harry Potter
   9               |   01/05/2020      |that           |18:26:52   |Jane Doe
   10              |   01/05/2020      |last           |21:27:36   |Adam Jones
   11              |   02/05/2020      |row            |06:09:42   |Joe Bloggs
   12              |   02/05/2020      |date           |07:00:02   |Iam Igor
   13              |   02/05/2020      |is today       |12:40:08   |Pinco Pallino
   ```

Keep in mind that doing (as you are doing):

```
If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value > WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value + TimeSerial(12, 0, 0) Then
    strDate = strDate - 1
    WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate
Else
    WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate
End If
```

is the same thing doing that:

```
If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value > WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value + TimeSerial(12, 0, 0) Then
    strDate = strDate - 1
End If
    WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate
```

In addition you have to think what does think you mind when you understand that if a cell contains 06:09:42 and the upper one contains 21:27:36 then you are talking about 2 different days? 
It's because the upper cell is more big than the lower cell, but the upper has to be a timestamp (date+time) smaller than the lower.

So `if` condition need to be something like:

```
If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value < WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
    strDate = strDate - 1
End If
```

And complete code would be:

```
Sub DateStamp()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    strDate = Date

    Do Until lRow = 2

        WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate

        'If upper cell has a time bigger than the one in the current cell
        'Than we are talking of two different days. Maybe is the day before.
        If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value < WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            strDate = strDate - 1
        End If
        lRow = lRow - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

This code will not fill the first data row (row number `2`). To do it you have to change the  `Until` condition of the `Do` loop in order to include row number `2` and in the case of row number `2` don't check the previous row (it doesn't contain a valid time).

```
Sub DateStamp()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    strDate = Date

    Do Until lRow < 2   'It stops when lRow is strictly less than 2. Include lRow = 2

        WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2).Value = strDate

        'Doesn't run for lRow = 2
        If lRow > 2 Then
            If WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Value < WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
                strDate = strDate - 1
            End If
        End If

        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

P.s. You can avoid using offsets in those cases

```
WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(0, -2)
WS1.Cells(lRow, 4).Offset(-1, 0)
```

replacing them with

```
WS1.Cells(lRow, 2)
WS1.Cells(lRow-1, 4)
```

Comment: @lgor Thank you for your time to explain where I had gone wrong but how to improve the code. I have run the code and it has done all 430,000 lines in a minute.

Comment: First step to improve: avoid the use of offset